# Reading in a table with non-standard row names in R?

Tags: r

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
       xyz ghj asd qwe
a / b:  1   2   3   4
c / d:  5   6   7   8
e / f:  9   10  11  12
        ...
        ...
```

I'm trying to use read.table(header = T) but it seems to be misinterpreting the row name. Is there a way to deal with this in read.table() or should I just use readLines()

Comment: Do you mean the row names rather than column names?

Comment: So the data doesn't appear to have a consistent delimiter. Where did such a file come from? Are you sure there's no way to output a CSV file or something? How exactly do you want the data formatted in R. You'll likely have to do some messy string manipulation to make the data somewhat normalized before reading into a data.frame. It looks like the problem is the row "names", not the column headers.

Comment: Maybe read.fwf() would help as well

Comment: @AllanCameron updated to row names

Comment: @MrFlick There's no csv equivalent of this txt file. I want to read the 1 2 3 4 part into a dataframe, so I'm looking for a way that might allow me to skip specific number of characters in each row (in this case, 8) while using read.table()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to just skip a few characters in each row using a `read.table` option.

Instead, you can call `read.table` twice, once for all the data after the first row, and the second time for the header.

Where your data are in a file called "test.txt", you would do:

```
library(magrittr)
tmp <- read.table(file="test.txt", sep="", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip=1)[, -c(1:3)] %>%
         setNames(read.table(file="test.txt", sep="", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, nrows=1))

> tmp
  xyz ghj asd qwe
1   1   2   3   4
2   5   6   7   8
3   9  10  11  12
>
```

Package `magrittr` is what gives you the pipe operator `%>%` that allows you to read the data and the header separately, but put them together in a single line. If you have a sufficiently-new R version you can use the `|>` operator instead, without the `magrittr` package.